# Disabling model warnings inside controller code

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, phpstorm

When I use models inside my controller code, I get "not found" warnings. I use phpstorm 4 and Cakephp 2.x. But it seems like a general case for CakePHP.

Assume that I have such code below. My IDE gives warning that "Signin" can't be found. I don't want to suppress warnings by changing preferences. How can I fix this?

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
/**
* MyController
*
* @property Signin $Signin
*/
class MyController extends AppController {
      public $uses = array('Signin');
      public function test() {
          $data = $this->Signin->find('all');
          debug($data);
     }
 }
```

**Edit:**
Similar issue is addressed here:
http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5466856
One of the user in forum said that this problem is related with Cake, not IDE.

Comment: Please create standalone test project (so it includes all files necessary to test it on another computer) and attach it to that forum thread -- maybe I can find what is happening.

Comment: Have you tried putting the `@property` annotation above the `$uses` declaration? In Netbeans this works fine for me. Its definitely not a Cake issue. If you use Annotations to find your Classes, it's your IDEs job to find them. Also check if you use Namespaces and add the prefixes accordingly.